# Django SQLite UPDATE

Tags: python, django, sqlite

I am developing a webapp using django. Generally, I want to keep track of how much time a user has devoted to a project. So when the user starts working, I am registering a "Change" object in the database with the user, the project, and what time he start working. Now, how can I get the same "Change" object to a different view to log the end time? In my best attempt I got an "IntegrityError NOT NULL constraint failed". Here is the code:

**views.py**

```
@login_required
def main(request):
    context = RequestContext(request)
    user=request.user
    if request.method=='POST':
        projectid=request.POST['project']
        project = Project.objects.get(pk=int(projectid))
        if project:
            change=Change(user=user, project=project,starttime=datetime.now())
            change.save()
            #return HttpResponse("I \'ve already start counting... You \'ve wasted 5 seconds already. Just joking. I don\'t know how to count...")
            return render_to_response('ProjectLogging/timer.html', {'change':change}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
        else:
            HttpResponse("Choose a valid project!")
    else:
        HttpResponse("Choose a POST method (???????)")

@login_required
def timer(request, change):
    user=request.user
    # schange=request.change
    if request.method=='POST':
        change=Change(endtime=datetime.now())
        change.save()
        return render_to_response('ProjectLogging/main.html',{'user':user, 'project_list':Project.objects.all()}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
    else:
        return HttpResponse("Something went wrong with timer view.")
```

**urls.py**

```
urlpatterns=patterns('ProjectLogging',
    url(r'^$', 'views.login', name="index"),
    url(r'^login/$', 'views.login', name="login"),
    url(r'^logout/$', 'views.logout', name="logout"),
    url(r'^main/$','views.main', name="main"),
    url(r'^timer/$', 'views.timer', {'change':'change'}),
)
```

and the **Change** model

```
class Change(models.Model):
    user=models.ForeignKey(User)
    project=models.ForeignKey('Project')
    starttime=models.DateTimeField(null=True,blank=True)
    endtime=models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)
    flagged=models.BooleanField(default=False, db_index=True)

    def __repr__(self):
        return ('Change in project %r from %r' % (self.project.title, self.user.username))

    def __unicode__(self):
        return ('%r in project: %r' % (self.user.get_full_name(), self.project.title))

    def user_changes(self, user):
        return self.filter(user==user)
```

Sorry for the primitive code. I m new to both Django and Python.

Comment: The 'Integrity Error' I get it's because the server waits for a whole new 'Change' object and doesn't retrieve the one that I want.

Comment: Can the user only have one change item active at a time?

Comment: I m not sure that I understand your question, but probably no.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the error is here:

```
change=Change(endtime=datetime.now())
change.save()
```

You are trying to create a new object...

Instead you need to get the previous created one and save it.

you need to pass the id to the post , get the object and save it again:

```
change = Change.objects.get(id=change_id)
change.endtime=datetime.now()
change.save()
```

This is what I would do:

change the url from this

```
url(r'^timer/$', 'views.timer', {'change':'change'}),
```

to this:

```
url(r'^timer/$', 'views.timer', name='timer'),
```

Pass the change_id in the form as a hidden input. Since you're not using django Forms, you'll have to write this

```
<input type="hidden" value="{{ change.id }}" name="change_id" />
```

Change the timer function to this:

```
@login_required
def timer(request):
    ...
    if request.method=='POST':
        try:
            change = Change.objects.get(id=request.POST.get('change_id'))
            change.endtime=datetime.now()
            change.save()
        except:
            ...
```

that should be ok

Comment: I tried your solution but I get a 'invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''' error. Probably because 'change_id' is empty.  How can I pass 'change_id' from the form (I ve told you I m newbie). Here is my form:
`{%block content%}`
 `<h2>You are working at project <h1>{{change.project.title}}</h1><br></h2>`
 `<p>You started at {{change.starttime}}</p>`
 `<form action="/timer/" method="post">`
  `{%csrf_token%}
  <input type="submit" value="Finished!">`
 `</form>`
`{%endblock%}`

Comment: great, you're using a form. I'll edit my answer. 2min

Comment: ok, just edit the url, add the input in the form and it should work fine

Comment: It seems to work now but I get another error in the admin page. :p Thanks a lot though!!